# Why do we need to return a function in the React Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with Material-UI components on the project and is using `AutoComplete` component in my app.

In the example from Material-UI team, I came across an interesting example of the AutoComplete Ajax data: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#asynchronous-requests

They are using React Hooks to fetch the data from the server:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;

    if (!loading) {
      return undefined;
    }

    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://country.register.gov.uk/records.json?page-size=5000');
      await sleep(1e3); // For demo purposes.
      const countries = await response.json();

      if (active) {
        setOptions(Object.keys(countries).map((key) => countries[key].item[0]));
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
  }, [loading]);
```

Why do we use `active` variable here? Why we return a function that changes this variable to `false`? It is always `true` in the `if-statement`.
Thanks in advance for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function returned from `useEffect` is a [`cleanup` function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1). It is called when the component un-mounts - and is usually used to unsubscribe to events, cancel pending promises etc that were used in the `useEffect`.

The `active` variable is used make sure that you aren't updating the state on something that doesn't exist anymore. It's somewhat like the [`isMounted`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) anti-pattern that existed in class components.

When you try to update state on an un-mounted component, React will throw a warning -

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.

Having the `active` variable prevents that in the following way:

- Your component loads
- The `useEffect` calls an `async` fetch - this will take time
- Now say, before the server from the response is returned, you navigate away from the page (or perform some other action that un-mounts the component)
- That will cause the component to unmount and the cleanup function to be called:

```
    return () => {
      active = false;
    };
```

- `active` is now set to `false`
- Finally, we get our response from the server. And now, it'll encounter the `false` `active` value, and not update the state.

```
      // active === false, 
      // this will skip `setOptions`
      if (active) {
        setOptions(...);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pattern which is used to avoid two situations:

1. updating the state if component containing this hook has already unmounted before HTTP request could complete.
2. avoid race conditions

Function returned by callback function of `useEffect` hook is used to perform the clean up, like `componentWillUnmount` in class based components. This cleanup function runs when the component unmounts or before running the effect next time.

So if component is unmounted when the HTTP request was in progress, cleanup function of useEffect hook will run and will set `active` to false. After that, whenever the result of HTTP request returns, state won't be updated because `active` will be false.

See [Effects with cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) section of react docs to understand the cleanup function of `useEffect` hook and see [Race Conditions](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#speaking-of-race-conditions) to better understand the problem related to race conditions that is solved here by using `active` variable.